# Check disk usage and the growth history

Tags: mac, disk-utility, macos, disk-space

Today I received a message saying there is only 18 GB left.

In the last few days I don't think I used so much space in the disk.

Is there some way to check the disk usage history? In a way to see how much disk was consumed in the last day/week/month.

Comment: There used to be a daily cronjob with output in Console for that, not sure if OS still has that. Last time I looked at that was in Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) application (a free trial is also available -- see the link).

This app help you to find out how you are using the space and so you can identify what is occupying a large amount of space in your HD. It does not provide a historical record, so unless you are using a tool and logging that information, you might have to focus on what's present now rather than looking back.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [this tool](https://apple.co/3mQmGm3) to monitor the free disk, that way you could keep an eye on the status bar and see how the disk space changes.

Comment: Do you have a non facebook link?

Comment: @KcFnMi Try now

Comment: Do I need to turn my vpn off to access that link?